# Palindrome string used by predefined function but unable to solve as it is showing only one error

Tags: javascript

// Unable to understand what is wrong in this code always showing string is not
// palindrome

```
                 **Check this**    


        <script>

      var isPalindrome = function (str) {
        const st = str.split("").reverse().join();
        console.log(st);

        if (str == st) {
          console.log("It is a palindrome");
        } else {
          console.log("It is not a palindrome");
        }
      };
      let str = "abba";

      isPalindrome(str);

    </script>

               //I have tried a lot. unable to understand why stack overflow is taking to much time to upload only showing err //
```

Comment: Just add parenthesis to `.join('')` exactlly like you did with `.split('')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isPalindrome = (str) => {
  const str2 = str.split("").reverse().join("");

  if (str == str2) {
    console.log("It is a palindrome");
  } else {
    console.log("It is not a palindrome");
  }
};

isPalindrome('aabb');
isPalindrome('abba');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
function palindrome(str) {
  let reversed = str.split('').reduce((acc, cur) => cur + acc, '');
  if (str === reversed) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
let str = "abba";
console.log(palindrome(str));
```